# Kindle Fire, Fire phone, and Amazon TV Emulators

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kindle-fire

I was trying to create Kindle Fire emulators to test apps for Kindle Fire tablet, fire phone, Amazon TV. I've followed the documentation but I couldn't create emulators for these. Can anybody tell me that whether Amazon is giving support for emulators or not?

Answer (score 4):

You need a basic SDK development setup using the Android SDK Manager with the latest versions of the following downloaded:

```
Android SDK Tools
Android SDK Platform-tools
Android SDK Build-tools
Android 4.2.2 API 17 SDK Platform
Android 4.0.3 API 15 SDK Platform
Android 2.3.3 API 10 SDK Platform
Android Support Library
```

Then you will need to add the various Amazon Add-on Site urls to the Android SDK Manager. To do this open the SDK Manager and go to `Tools` -> `Manage Add-on Sites..` on the main menu. Next go to the `User Defined Sites` and add the following URLs:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/addon.xml
http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml
```

Now close, and re-open your SDK manager (or use `Reload` from the `Packages` menu).

Next download **all** of the Amazon/Kindle related stuff using the SDK manager. This includes:

```
[Under Extras]
  Amazon AVD Launcher (Windows)
  Kindle Fire Device Definitions
  (optional) Kindle Fire USB Driver
[Android 2.3.3 (API 10)]
  Kindle Fire
[Android 4.0.3 (API 15)]
  Kindle Fire (2nd Gen)
  Kindle Fire HD 7"
  Kindle Fire HD 8.9"
[Android 4.2.2 (API 17)]
  Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon
  Amazon Fire TV SDK Addon
```

Once all of these have been downloaded, open your SDK folder and browse to `\Extras\Amazon\AVDLauncherWindows` and run `amazonavd.bat`. Now create your desired devices from there.

For reference here are the Amazon documentation links:

[Kindle Fire](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/kindle-fire)
[Fire Phone](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone)
[Fire TV](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv)